# Write a C program to count number of digits in any number

Tags: c

What am i doing wrong in this code ?
There are no errors but if i enter a 4 digit number the output it is 1272 !!

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int i,n=0;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter a number");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    while(i>=9)
    {
        i=i/10;
        n++;
    }
    n++;
    printf("This is a %d digit number",n);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: You could use a debugger to step through your code and find out by yourself?

Comment: You've never initialized `n`, make it `n=0`

Comment: There is no such header file called `<conio.h>` in standard C. `void main()` is also wrong, it should be `int main(void)`

Comment: `n` should be initialised to 0.

Comment: @Destructor `void main()` may not be wrong.  It is implementation defined if it is acceptable.  Still, best to return `int`.

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla Thank you :)

Comment: `while(i>=9)
    {
        i=i/10;
        n++;
    }` is not correct.  Hint: what if `i == 9`?

Comment: "count number of digits in **any** number" --> Code has trouble with negative numbers.

Comment: @chux Yes,it is having trouble with negitive numbers !! Can you please suggest how to overcome that problem ?

Comment: `int n = 0; do { n++; i /= 10; } while (i);`

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's **undefined behavior** because you have used uninitialized local variable.

Do not use automatic storage variable before it has been initialized yields undefined behavior

C standard is 6.3.2.1 p2:

> If the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that
>   could have been declared with the register storage class (never had
>   its address taken), and that object is uninitialized (not declared
>   with an initializer and no assignment to it has been performed prior
>   to use), the behavior is undefined.

Just initialize your variables and avoid a potential headache in the future.

So, in your program initialize `n` to `0`.

```
int n = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `n`  to `0`. You are incrementing whatever **garbage** value is in memory for `n`.